# Как получить только значение ассоциативного массива в PHP (без ключа)?

Tags: php, массивы

У меня есть класс `KeyValueSystem`, который анализирует файл, в котором хранятся пары строк *ключ=значение* и строит из этого ассоциативный массив.

```
<?php
class KeyValueSystem {
    protected $array = [];
    
    public static function parse_File($file_name) {
        $file_data = explode('\n', file_get_contents($file_name));
        $parsed_data = new KeyValueSystem;
        foreach ($file_data as $line) {
            $line = explode('=', $line);
            $parsed_data->add_Pair($line[0], $line[1]);
        }
        return $parsed_data;
    }
    
    public function add_Pair($key, $value) {
        $this->array[$key] = $value;
    }
    
    public function delete_Pair($key) {
        unset($this->array[$key]);
    }
    
    public function get($key) {
        return $this->array[$key];
    }
}
?>
```

В корне проекта есть файл `example.fgh`.

```
hello=Hello, world!
howru=How are you?
```

С основного файла PHP я создаю объект `KeyValueSystem` с использованием метода `parse_File`, который читает тот файл и создаёт ассоциативный массив.

```
<?php
require_once('libraries/smarty/Smarty.class.php');
require_once('tools.php');

$smarty = new Smarty;

$data = KeyValueSystem::parse_File('example.fgh');
$smarty->assign('assigned_text', "{$data->get('hello')}");
$smarty->display('pages/home.tpl');
?>
```

Здесь я пытаюсь отобразить текст из файла под ключом *howru*, но возникает странная проблема — на странице отображается не только значение из ассоциативного массива, но после и его ключ. Мне нужно чтобы отображалось только значение (текст *How are you?*).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что исправить в коде?

Comment: Так может у вас в шаблоне оно захардкожено. Или через смарти что-то та мнаписано в шаблоне. Так  что надо смотреть не на этот код, а на `home.tpl` и что там

Comment: ну а для проверки текущего кода - есть отладка (debugging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заменить

```
explode('\n', $str);
```

на

```
explode("\n", $str);
```

Т.к. в одинарных кавычках это уже не управляющая последовательность, а просто строка ( https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double )